# How can I get all information that gets printed to the terminal including errors

Tags: python, terminal, discord.py

I would like to add all this information that goes/prints on the terminal to a separate file. Since my VPS goes down quite often and I would like to monitor any and all errors. This is for a discord bot by the way. So I have specific error handlers for certain commands.

Comment: I can think of at least 3 options. 1) *print()* has an option to specify an output file 2) consider the *logging* module 3) if running your script from a Unix-type shell, just redirect the stdout and stderr to a file of your choosing

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the script of your bot followed by `> file.txt`, anything shown on the stdout (the output of `print()`) will be written in `file.txt`

You can learn more on that by googling `cmd redirect output to file` :)